# How can hover on parent but not on child input

Tags: html, css

Basically I have

```css
.parent {

  height:200px;

}

.title {

  user-select: none;

}

.parent:hover {

 background:green;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hello Input!">
</div>
```

and I would like the hover effect to be disabled when hovering the input.

How can I do this?

One improvement would be to automatically disable the hover effect when cursor change to `text` or `cursor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:not(:has(input:hover))` for a CSS-only solution, but please note that `:has()` is not supported universally in all browsers yet.

```css
.parent {
  height:200px;
}

.title {
  user-select: none;
}

.parent:hover:not(:has(input:hover)) {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hello Input!">
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could listen in JavaScript for whether the input is hovered:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('mouseenter', ({ target }) => {
  target.closest('.parent').classList.add('foo');
});

input.addEventListener('mouseleave', ({ target }) => {
  target.closest('.parent').classList.remove('foo');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  height:200px;
}

.title {
  user-select: none;
}

.parent:hover:not(.foo) {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hello Input!">
</div>
```

Comment: your first soultion doesn't work on firefox so that's not an option are you sure javascript is the only solution I already have plenty of listeners and would like to lighten as much as possible.Thanks in advance.